# Min and max with conditions in single sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like

```
create table appointments
(
    id                  serial   not null constraint appointments_pkey           primary key,
    patient_id          varchar(255)                                   not null,
    date                timestamp(0)  not null 
);
```

I want to get date of next appointment and previous appointment in single query.

I created query as

```
 SELECT
        (
                    SELECT MIN(ap.date) FROM appointments ap
                    WHERE ap.date >= NOW() AND ap.patient_id = '1'
        ) AS next,
        (
                    SELECT MAX(ap.date) FROM appointments ap
                    WHERE ap.date < NOW() AND ap.patient_id = '1'
        ) AS last
```

which works as expected, but I think it is not optimized because two subqueries.
Can you help me to optimize me such query,please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `case when expression`

```
select 
    min(case when ap.date >= NOW() then ap.date end) next,
    max(case when ap.date < NOW() then ap.date end) last
from appointments ap
where ap.patient_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is probably fine.  I would more likely use `union all` for the purpose, though:

```
(SELECT ap.*
 FROM appointments ap
 WHERE ap.patient_id = 1 AND ap.date >= NOW()
 ORDER BY ap.date DESC
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) UNION ALL
(SELECT ap.*
 FROM appointments ap
 WHERE ap.patient_id = 1 AND ap.date < NOW()
 ORDER BY ap.date ASC
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) ;
```

This returns the entire rows, not just the dates.

Both this query and your can take advantage of an index on `appointments(patient_id, date)`.  Other solutions such as conditional aggregation and window functions probably are not going to take advantage of indexes so the entire table would need to be scanned.